# java.time equivalent of Joda-Time `withTimeAtStartOfDay`? (get first moment of the day)

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

In the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class offers a method [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--) to get the first moment of the day. You might think of that moment as "midnight". That first moment is usually the time `00:00:00.000` but not always.

Does the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) found in Java 8 and later have an equivalent feature?

Comment: AFAIK not directly, but you could do something like `LocalDateTime.now().withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);`, which is a little long winded but should achieve the same result :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent is using a special method, [atStartOfDay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-), in the class [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.now(zoneId).atStartOfDay(zoneId);
```

Please also note that the equivalent of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is not [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), but [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The [`zoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) parameter matters here. Concrete example for migration - see also [timezone website](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo?tz=America/Sao_Paulo) for details about [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) transition in Brazil:

**Joda-Time (old way)**

```
DateTime dt = 
  new DateTime(2015, 10, 18, 12, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo"));
dt = dt.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
System.out.println(dt); // 2015-10-18T01:00:00.000-02:00
```

Note that this code would even throw an exception for midnight in first line with call to [constructor](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-int-int-int-int-int-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-).

**java.time (new way)**

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
ZonedDateTime zdt =
  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 10, 18, 12, 0, 0, 0, zoneId);
zdt = zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(zoneId);
System.out.println(zdt); // 2015-10-18T01:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

The second program statement behaves differently than Joda-Time because it will not throw an exception but silently shifts the local time by the size of the gap in question, here one hour. This means, if you had chosen midnight, the result would be the same (namely at 1:00). If you had chosen 00:30, then the result would be 01:30. The example given above chooses noon as input.

To quote the doc for [ZonedDateTime.of(…)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneId-):

> In most cases, there is only one valid offset for a local date-time. In the case of an overlap, when clocks are set back, there are two valid offsets. This method uses the earlier offset typically corresponding to "summer".
>
> In the case of a gap, when clocks jump forward, there is no valid offset. Instead, the local date-time is adjusted to be later by the length of the gap. For a typical one hour daylight savings change, the local date-time will be moved one hour later into the offset typically corresponding to "summer".

A 100%-migration of all details like exception behaviour and applied DST transition strategies is not possible because both libraries are too different. But that is your guideline:

- replace `DateTime` by `ZonedDateTime`
- consider switching to `LocalDate` for intermediate calculations (see example)
- use explicit references to the timezone and replace `DateTimeZone` by `ZoneId`

Comment: If the second line (`ZonedDateTime.of`) slides forward or backward, why do we need the third line, `zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(zoneId)`?

Comment: @BasilBourque First let me say thanks for your English corrections. About the meaning of the second line, well, without this line "zdt" will just be at noon (the original value 12:00). But the question is about the START of the day. An alternative and maybe more suitable answer to your question would be: `ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 10, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, zoneId)` which yields the time one hour after midnight (silently pushing forward by one hour). Personally I find the style using the method `atStartOfDay(...)` more expressive.

Comment: @BasilBourque It is a missing feature in both libraries not to offer alternative transition strategies. The behaviour of Joda-Time just to throw an exception for invalid local times is hardly satisfying. And JSR-310 had thrown out this feature (was once there in [Threeten](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/time/calendar/ZoneResolvers.html)!) and is now only limited to PUSH_FORWARD-strategy.

Comment: @BasilBourque To make it more clear. I don't like implicit defaults and silent adjustments at all. If the API offers any chance to make the push-forward-adjustment more clear (here `atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`) then I prefer and advocate that. Otherwise I regret that JSR-310 offers far too many implicit defaults by design.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `LocalDate` to do this:

```
// or a similar factory method to get the date you want
LocalDateTime startOfDay = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
```

> Combines this date with the time of midnight to create a LocalDateTime at the start of this date. This returns a LocalDateTime formed from this date at the time of midnight, 00:00, at the start of this date.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--

Comment: @MenoHochschild What makes you think that? He even included a link to the JDK 8 API docs for the method - it's not Joda Time code.

Comment: @Jesper Please look at the code example again. JSR-310 (Java-8) does not use public constructors but static factory methods.

Answer (score 4):

## Java Time `truncatedTo`

While this is an old question, I've just discovered another way to do this, using [truncation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-), which to me feels more elegant:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime today = now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS); // today, midnight
```

This is shorter to type and requires fewer intermediate values in code.  As far as I can tell, the semantics are the same as the accepted answer's.

Answer (score 1):

## `TemporalAdjuster`

Every [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) is also a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html), so if can be passed to the `with()` method of most temporal types and will update the time fields to match.

That is:

```
@Test
public void date_time_at_start_of_day() throws Exception {
    assertThat(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-22T12:27:00")
                            .with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT),
               equalTo(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-22T00:00:00")));
    assertThat(OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-05-22T12:27:00+01:00")
                             .with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT),
               equalTo(OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-05-22T00:00:00+01:00")));
    assertThat(ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-05-22T12:27:00+01:00[Europe/London]")
                            .with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT),
               equalTo(ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-05-22T00:00:00+01:00[Europe/London]")));
}
```