# Is there an easier way to get start and end of current day time than this?

Tags: java, date, datetime

To get the end time of the day.

```
Date now = new Date();
now.setHours(23);
now.setMinutes(59);
now.setSeconds(59);
```

To get the stat time of the day.

```
Date now = new Date();
now.setHours(00);
now.setMinutes(00);
now.setSeconds(00);
```

Comment: To be clear, you want a today's local date 1. set at midnight and 2. just before midnight at the end of the day?

Comment: What are you using this for?

Comment: This looks pretty easy to me? Just wrap the code in some methods.

Comment: Looks easy, but isn't necessarily correct. The classic example of where this is wrong is in Asia/Gaza on the day daylight savings starts - there is no midnight. This is why Jodatime has the [`DateTime.withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method.

Comment: Also, days don't end at 23:59:59, they end at the instant the next day starts. But the last instant representable by a Java Date on a day is 23:59:59.999 (unless there is a leap second, of course).

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you could use the `java.tome.LocalDate` class instead, that doesn't have a time notion. And from there, if you want a time, then use something like `LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()`

Comment: Also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293748/java-time-equivalent-of-joda-time-withtimeatstartofday-get-first-moment-of-t

Answer (score 0):

`Date.set()` methods are deprecated. Use `Calendar` instead.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 23, 59, 59);
```

**CLARIFICATION**: A day does not *end* at 23:59:59. The above code just creates two `Calendar` instances, one set at 0:00:00 and the other one at 23:59:59 of the current day.

Comment: Don't forget the milliseconds

Comment: Just created two `Calendar` instances exactly as the OP indicated; the first one set at 0:00:00 and the other at 23:59:59. Declaring either of them as the "boundaries" of a certain day is completely wrong. Nonetheless, the OP can use any of the 7 constructor the `GregorianCalendar` class provides.